# Solution Folder Not Showing in Visual Studio 2010 - How Can I Make It Visible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I created a new Blank Solution in Visual Studio 2010, then I did an Add New Project, and the Solution node no longer shows in the Solution Explorer.

Further, when I try to do a second Add New Project, I get the error:

> Cannot add the item because the item to add it to is not a solution folder or the solution.

What happened to the Solution node?

Where is it, so that I can highlight it and add a second project to my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to view Solution explorer. **Go to View > Solution explorer**.

Or press **Ctrl+Alt+L.**

And solution window will appear.

Comment: Hi @abhishek_Thomas - Your answer will show the Solution Explorer tab/window in Visual Studio, however the question is in regard to the Solution *folder* within the Solution Explorer.  So, although your answer is accurate - it does not properly answer the question.

Comment: I added an edit to explain more work is required to achieve the solution.  If the edit is accepted, I hope to remove my downvote, as there is nothing wrong with the part you wrote, it was just missing the next part.

Answer (score 85):

Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, check "Always show solution"

[image: Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, check "Always show solution"]

Trivial update:

I'm on Visual Studio 2010, Ultimate edition. Windows 2008 R2, Enterprise edition, SP1. My guess the difference between @arrocharGeek screenshot and mine is I turn off all the vista/win7/2008r2 eye candy to make it look "normal."
[image: About dialog box]

Comment: Note: If you don't see "Projects and Solutions" you much check the "Show all settings" checkbox in the bottom left of the dialog.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that dialog box, where can I find that one?

Comment: True, mine does not match that one - are you using Visual Studio 2010?  BTW "Always show solution" appears to have been checked off by default in vs 2010

Comment: giving you the accepted answer and a vote, since your answer was lightning fast and beautifully terse.  You rock.

Comment: Note: If you have VS 2010 SP1 and/or your dialog does not look like the one above, see dialog in my post below.

Comment: I had to this even though I am using the Solution Navigator add-in from Productivity Power Tools--I couldn't add a new project even though the Solution Navigator always shows the solution.

Answer (score 18):

You need to show the solution as follows:

- Navigate to Tools | Options
- Check the "Show all settings" checkbox in the bottom left of the Options dialog
- Navigate to the "Projects and Solutions" | "General" section
- Check the "Always show solution" checkbox

[image: Visual Studio 2010 Tools | Options Dialog Box]

The "Solution solution-name (n projects)" will now show, and you can highlight that node to Add New Project from there.

---

Trivial Update: My VS 2010 is SP1Rel, and I am on Win7 Enterprise SP 1:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Help/About Dialog, Detail]