# Visual Studio 2012 Blank Solution Disappears

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

**Problem:** In Visual Studio 2012, you create a blank solution and the solution node instantly disappears from the solution explorer, preventing you from adding a project.

**Note:** This problem is distinct from the settings issue in Visual Studio 2010, where you simply enable the option, "always show solution".  See: [Solution Folder Not Showing in Visual Studio 2010 - How Can I Make It Visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457935/solution-folder-not-showing-in-visual-studio-2010-how-can-i-make-it-visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I added the project in TFS before creating the blank solution.  No matter how many times I tried create the solution, even by creating a dummy class library, the solution node always disappeared.  The work-around was to delete the TFS project and then create the blank solution:

C:>tfsdeleteproject /collection:https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection myproject

Once the TFS project was deleted, I was able to create the blank solution and add a class library...