# Renamed SSIS Package and Now Don't Have Access to my Solutions

Tags: ssis

I made a goof and renamed my SSIS package without fully understanding what I was doing.  Now I get "one or more solutions couldn't be added..." I then go to my solution explorer and no solutions are there.  Please note that I've been working on this project for 6 months.    I checked the project obj folder and all my solutions are there.  I'm pretty sure I have to rename something else.  Will somebody please help me.  I am an intern and am FREAKING OUT.

Comment: Should I delete the old .suo?

Comment: Did you rename the "package" or the actual "project"? Based on your error message, I'm guessing it's project.

Comment: I renamed both the project and package

Comment: You've lost nothing. What is happening is that Visual Studio is looking for a specific named file and it's not finding it

Comment: I read a forum on how to do it for C# solutions but it was for a way older version of VS and some dialogue boxes in the sites diagrams didn't seem applicable to my 2010 version.  What is the best steps to take.  I did notice 2 .suo files in my project.  One of which is the older name.  Should I delete the older one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine what's happening. I am using SSIS 2012 in this example but the steps will be the same for 2005 to 2014. This assumes you have turned off "hide file extensions".

Visual Studio is an Integrated Development Environment, IDE, for developing software. The outermost concept is a Solution. See 1 below. Solutions solve a problem as a whole. A solution might need multiple tools to solve a problem. A tool in this case, is a Project (#2). Depending on the type of project, different folders and such will appear in section 3. This is an example of an SSIS project.

If you don't see your solution, there's a question for that [Solution Folder Not Showing in Visual Studio 2010 - How Can I Make It Visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457935/solution-folder-not-showing-in-visual-studio-2010-how-can-i-make-it-visible/7457962#7457962)

[image]

If I Rename the project JeffOrris to JeffOrris2 and close Visual Studio, it will prompt me to save changes to JeffOrris.sln (and optionally, the project). If I click No, when I reopen the solution, I am greeted with the following error message along with Visual Studio indicating that my project JeffOrris is unavailable. :'(

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.

Please see the Output Window for details.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

To start fixing things, you have to get Visual Studio to play ball. You can do this one of two routes. The first is to Add the renamed project back into the solution. Add... Existing Project... and then find your .dtproj file (or .whatever it was with 2005/2008) Assuming that loads fine, you can right click on the one that isn't loading and select Remove. Then click "Save All" or Ctrl-Shift-S

[image]

Option 2, which is what I do is to go mucking about with files. Find where your .SLN is. If your project is still open, it will indicate it under properties but once it's bolloxed then you'd need to right click and choose Open Folder in File Explorer.

[image]

However you get here, look at what you have.

A solution is represented on disk by a `.sln` file. That's a text file, might be UTF-8 but it's human readable text. The .suo file is binary that keeps track of what you have open and such. It doesn't matter, the .sln does.

[image]

Take a peek inside your solution file. Knowledge is only good for you

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
Project("{159641D6-6404-4A2A-AE62-294DE0FE8301}") = "JeffOrris", "JeffOrris\JeffOrris.dtproj", "{631559E9-5ED5-4F63-B74E-BFB6CBAE89C5}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Development|Default = Development|Default
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {631559E9-5ED5-4F63-B74E-BFB6CBAE89C5}.Development|Default.ActiveCfg = Development
        {631559E9-5ED5-4F63-B74E-BFB6CBAE89C5}.Development|Default.Build.0 = Development
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Of importance is the line starting with Project. That says I, the Solution, have a Project called JeffOrris and the project file can be found, relative to my location, at Folder called JeffOrris and inside there a file named JeffOrris.dtproj

The "trick" then is to make your subject and verbs agree. Or in this case, make your Solution and your .dtproj file agree. That'd be #6 below. After saving the solution file, Visual Studio should prompt you to reload it and whoosh, your project is back.

[image]

If you have inadvertently renamed the .dtproj file, then you can rename it back. Again, save all

Comment: Thank your for the precise processes and options.  I chose option 2.  I just edited the .sln in notepad and switch the names in the path.  WORKED LIKE A CHARM!!!